# Collections.min() method confusion in list of string which holds double values

Tags: java

I have a list of strings which holds the double value. Since it holds the double value. i used Collection.min to find the minimum value in the list.

Unfortunately i get a wrong result.

What is the best way to find the smallest double value in the list of strings?

Below is the code snippet with different results.

```
    String a = "5.0";
    String b = "7.0";
    String c = "11.0";
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add(a);
    test.add(b);
    test.add(c);
    System.out.println(Collections.min(test)); // Result 11.0

    test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add(a);
    test.add(b);
    System.out.println(Collections.min(test)); // 5.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your list isn't holding double values, it holding strings, strings are sorted on alphabetical order

Comment: If you don't want to use "String comparison", then convert these Strings to doubles first ... obviously.

Comment: Convert the `string`s to `double`s.

Comment: This is where the `map` predicate function is a god sent in Java 8 Lambda. :D

Comment: And when you figure out this one read up [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `Collections.min` on a list of `String`s, you get the `String` that comes first in lexicographical order. That's "11.0" in your example.

You'll have to convert your `List` to a `List<Double>` in order for `Collections.min` to give the result you want. Alternately, use can use `public static <T> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)` and pass to it a `Comparator<String>` that parses the `String`s into `double`s and compares the doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from java Doc of Collections.min :

> Returns the minimum element of the given collection, according to the 
>   natural ordering of its elements.

So the result is normal, it the natural ordering of strings.